# Improve scroll performance with scaled images in chrome

Tags: android, performance, google-chrome, scroll, repaint

I am working on a web application where I have playlist with track info and an artwork. The artwork is a `100x100px` image which is scaled down to `50x50px` to support high resolution displays. I started observing a weird jank while scroll and a little bit of googling brought me to this link — http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/scrolling/#toc-resizing

> If you're sending large images to a device and then scaling them down using CSS or image dimension attributes, you're more likely to see this happen. Of course the amount by which the browser has to rescale images, and the frequency with which it has to do this, is going to affect your page's performance as they happen on the main browser thread, and therefore block other work from taking place.

One solution that I think might work is to simply hide the images at the time of scrolling and show the scrolling stops. This would definitely effect the user's experience I think.

Website Reference : https://funag.github.io
PS: open in android chrome to observe the janks while scrolling